# Upgrading Active Directory from 2000 to 2008

Tags: active-directory

Our config is currently:

- 1 Windows 2000 domain controller running ISA2000, dhcp, dns
- 1 Windows 2003 domain controller as main file server, prob cert server as well, dhcp, dns
- 1 Windows 2008/Exchange2010 domain controller as Exchange server, DHCP,DNS

Currently getting FRS errors on files server journalwrap error
Currently getting FRS errors on other DC's can't replicate from above

Exchange DC holds Schema, rid, pdc, and infrastructure roles
File Server holds Domain naming operation master role

WOW, I didn't set this up, just inherited it.  Am I right to assume that fixing the FRS errors is #1, what do I need to do for that?  set enable journalwrap auto restore in registry?

Demote W2000 domain controller, should that have any implications for ISA? We have Forefront to be deployed but that's another day

Transfer Domain Naming Role to Exchange server (I know or think having an Exchange server as DC isn't best practice)  We will be getting another server W2008 to replace current file server and I thought it could takeover all roles once deployed

Demote W2k3 file server and then raise functional domain level to 2008

Am I missing anything other that the sense to walk away?

Thanks

Comment: How large is the AD organization?  # of users/computers/groups/objects?  Are those all of the servers or just the ones with DC roles?  I ask because my first thought is (if possible) to look at consolidation, clean up of roles, and using ADMT to move everything to a new clean domain structure.

Comment: How is this even possible as Exchange 2010 is not supposed to install if there is a windows 2000 DC in the domain..

Comment: Don't walk away. RUN.

Comment: I've always told myself that "create a new forest and migrate accounts and data over to it" is rarely the right answer to a domain upgrade, but you've certainly managed to show me an exception to that. I'd not even *think* about upgrading this mess until you've sorted out precisely what is going on and got it stable.

Comment: Either migrate to a new domain and have the clients deal with the down time or run away from the environment ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer these link..

Hope it helps for you

http://www.linkedin.com/groupItem?view=&gid=1914747&type=member&item=194138921&qid=2932ab64-c398-419e-b6f8-e6cb1fe1b0fb&trk=group_most_recent_rich-0-b-ttl&goback=.gmr_1914747

http://www.petri.co.il/forums/showthread.php?t=34657

http://forums.speedguide.net/showthread.php?277589-Active-Directory-Upgrade-2000-2008

Hope it helps for you.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Well if the person would read the links he would get the essentials part of the answer but anyways i got this i would keep in mind to post the essentila part and then the link

Comment: The point of StackExchange is to actually *have* the content directly. In 6 months those links might not work anymore, at which point, this answer is completely irrelevant. Or even worse, and I've seen this happen frequently, the site admins change something and those links go someplace else entirely! Damn dirty sticky wickets.

Comment: agreeing to your statement trully its true after 6 months link might not work any more